# Variadic template operator<<

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, variadic-templates

I'm trying to change some of my functions `foo()` into `operator<<()`, simply for the sake of getting some "half C/half C++" code to look more like C++. Happens, though, I've got stuck at the following *transformation step*:

```
template <class... T>
inline const size_t foo(const T&... data) {
    return sizeof...(T);
}
struct bar {
    template <class... T>
    inline const size_t operator<<(const T&... data) {
        return sizeof...(T);
    }
};
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    bar a;
    std::cout << ">>> length " << foo(1, 2, 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ">>> length " << (a << 1 << 2) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ">>> length " << (a << 1 << 2 << 3) << std::endl;
    std::cout << ">>> length " << (a << 1 << 2 << 3 << 4) << std::endl;
}
```

From the output:

```
$ ./a.out 
>>> length 3
>>> length 4
>>> length 32
>>> length 512
```

I conclude the first computation is performed upon `a << 1`, and the subsequent values are shifted accordingly. Yet, I'm failing to see how I could rewrite `foo()`, as to provide a `operator<<()` *interface* to users of `struct bar` -- of course, without changing `foo()` semantics.

In case there's no way to pass `class T...` as parameter to `operator<<()`, the function would be naturally less efficient than `foo()`, as it would be called many times. Is there any reasonable C++ construct for this, or sticking to `foo()` is the only/best option here?

**Context**:

These `foo()` functions are senders/receivers to network communication. I thought that would be better to provide a more "C++" interface, with a sender/receiver stream, writable/readable using `<<` and `>>` operators -- other than using regular functions `foo(...)`.

Comment: What's "C+-code"? Some weird construct, half C, half programming language?

Comment: So to properly answer the question, what are each of these actually doing?

Comment: @chris I've added some *context* to the problem; hope it clarifies the question.

Comment: I'm just really reluctant to say it will be as inefficient as you think it will.

Comment: @chris Yep, it must boil down close to the original function, after some compiler optimizations. Yet, I still can't see how to rewrite `foo()` using those operators. The point is: for my particular application, I need to know whether the function has been called one at a time `a << 1; a << 2`, or chained `a << 1 << 2;`. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language is doing what you are asking it to do.

With associativity, the following are equivalent (`<<` and `>>` are left-to-right associative):

```
a << 1 << 2
(a << 1) << 2
```

The call `a << 1` calls your user-defined operator, which in turn returns a `size_t`. That's why the types for next call are the following: `size_t << int` (which is a simple bitwise shift).

You need to use expression templates. The idea is the following (**[live example here](http://ideone.com/K7NYrh)**):

```
template<typename... args>
struct stream_op
{
};

template<typename... A, typename B>
stream_op<A..., B> operator<<(stream_op<A...> a, B b)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

So, the following occur (with `a` as a `stream_op<>`):

```
a << 1 << 2
------
  |
  v
-------------------------------------------
stream_op<int> operator<<(stream_op<>, int) << 2
--------------                                ---
     |                                         |
     |             +---------------------------+
     v             v
--------------    ---
stream_op<int> << int
--------------    ---
       |           |
       |           +---------------------------+
       +----------------------------+          |
                                    v          v
                              --------------  ---
stream_op<int,int> operator<<(stream_op<int>, int)
------------------
        |
        v
------------------
stream_op<int,int> // <- Expected result
```

Then you just have to put a method to convert `stream_op` to int (or to whatever you want).

A note on performances: with these expression templates, a part of the data is encoded in the type, so normally it should be as fast as a direct call to `foo(...)`.