# Constructor for boolean expression, not the result

Tags: c++, binding, conditional-statements, state-machine

I have created a template class called binding_condition so that I can abstract permutations of conditions to a single object. Currently it works with passing a lambda and any variables that need to be checked, but I find the lambda to be misleading since it needs to capture the variables I am referencing.

for example:

```
bool someVal = true;
int h = 10;
double p = 99.8;
char c = 'C';

binding_condition<bool> bc(
    [] (bool b) 
{ return b; }, 
someVal);

binding_condition<bool, int> bc2(
    [] (bool b, int i) 
{ return b && (i > 9); }, 
someVal, h);

binding_condition<bool, int, double> bc3(
    [] (bool b, int i, double d) 
{ return b && (i > 9) && (d < 100); }, 
someVal, h, p);

binding_condition<bool, int, double, char> bc4(
    [] (bool b, int i, double d, char c) 
{ return b && (i > 9) && (d < 100) && c == 'C'; }, 
someVal, h, p, c);
```

This allows me to abstract some complex condition into a single name:

```
if (ThisComplexCondition) ...
else if (ThisOtherComplexCondition ...
...
```

However I am wondering if there is way, either with expression templates or some other method, to allow syntax like this:

```
 binding_condition<bool, int, double> ComplexCondition = myClass.isTrue() && someThing.id < 100 && someDouble > 30.2;
```

I realize the above expression is not particularly creative, but consider this next one:

```
// analyzing chords in music to roman numeral notation, detect modulations, etc

// isChordRelatedToKey (the chord can be made from the current key

// isNeopolitan (the chord is a bii6 of the current key
   // is major
   // letter() is II/ii (ie C# major in C major is not a neapolitan, but Db major is)

// isSecondaryDominant 
   // chord is major
   // chord is dominant of next chord (requires a new temporary key of next chord

// isSecondaryDiminished
   // chord is diminished, and is the viio of the next chord
// all other forms of secondary, which means a ii/V in C major is A minor, which is also the vi of the key, and the iii/IV is also A minor

// nested secondary chords ie I - V - V/V - vii/V/V (C major, G major, D major, C# diminished)  

// isModulation
   // the current string of chords is not related to the current Key anymore
```

I want to implement some sort of statemachine, package these restrictions into objects, and simply check like:

```
if (isModulation) ...
if (isSecondary) ... // recursive
if (isChordNoRelation) ... // some chord that makes no sense from previous string
```

But baby steps at a time. Right now I just want to know if I can assign and store an expression, with whatever variables/functions being referenced in that expression.

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is feasible using expression templates. On [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868718/variadic-template-operator/17869231#17869231) I talk a bit about expression templates, and the idea behind it. You can use it for your problem (btw it will quite a big block of code).

Answer (score 0):

What is wrong with lambda closures, capturing the variables? You don't need to have them passed as parameters. In your first example, you can do this:

```
bool someVal = true;
int h = 10;
double p = 99.8;
char c = 'C';

auto bc4 = [&](){return someVal && (h > 9) && (p < 100) && c == 'C';};

//later:
if(bc4()) 
{
  /*...*/ 
}
```

and for the econd example:

```
auto ComplexCondition = [&]() { return myClass.isTrue() && someThing.id < 100 && someDouble > 30.2;};
```

The lambda expressions prodice closures that capture the mentioned variables by reference, so the values are evaluated when the closure operator() is called:

```
bool someVal = true;
int h = 10;
double p = 99.8;
char c = 'C';

auto bc4 = [&](){return someVal && (h > 9) && (p < 100) && c == 'C';};

if(bc4()) //gives true
{ /* ... */ }

p *= 2;
if (bc4()) {} //gives false, since p > 100
```