# Handling variable data using << operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, iostream

I have a piece of code for sending data to remote side, it is acting a little like [picojson](https://github.com/kazuho/picojson), for example:

```
server::value::object obj;
obj["cmd"] = server::value("test");
obj["url"] = server::value(url);
...
obj["code"] = server::value(std::to_string(code));

server::value v(obj);
client.send_to_server(v.process());
```

As long as there is something to send, there will be a block like this.

These lines are used in so many places in my project that I'm thinking of using a function or << operator to replace it, which should be able to handle variable arguments.

A << operator version would be like:

```
Data d << "cmd" << "test"
       << "url" << url
       << ... << ...
       << "code" << code;
client.send_to_server(d);
```

Is this a good idea doing so? How to implement it?

Thanks.

Comment: I'll give you a hint: `Data& operator<<(Data& data, const std::string& str);` for strings.

Comment: I've asked the same question a few days ago; see if [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17868718/variadic-template-operator) fits your need. I was planning the writing of a serializer too. (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would write it differently:

```
d << add_value("cmd", "test")
  << add_value("url", url)
  << add_value(..., ...)
  << add_value("code", code)
  ;
```

Why? It's clearer and allows better type control.

So you create a class, say `__add_value_temp` which holds both the name and the value, a function `add_value` that creates this class, and write a << operator

```
Data &operator<<(Data &d, const __add_value_temp &val){
  d.add(val.name,val.val);
  return d;
}
```

Better yet - instead of `__add_value_temp` you can use an `std::pair`, and use `std::make_pair` instead of `add_value`!

```
Data &operator<<(Data &d, const std::pair<std::string,std::string> &val){
  d.add(val.first,val.second);
  return d;
}

...
Data d;
d << std::make_pair("cmd", "test")
  << std::make_pair("url", url)
  << std::make_pair(..., ...)
  << std::make_pair("code", code)
  ;
```

(last note: might be smart to write the `operator<<` templated on the types of the `pair`, so that you can pass things by reference and generally maybe avoid unneeded copying)

Comment: BTW - writing the `;` one line after helps with copying / pasting various values, as well as allows easy commenting of lines (of the last line, for example).

Answer (score 1):

Designing an API like that is not a good idea, because it is extremely error-prone.

A seemingly similar idea worked fine with output streams for a simple reason: the data that you put into the stream for output is treated uniformly. Anything that you put into `<<` as an argument becomes part of the output, apart from stream manipulators, which control how the output is to be presented.

Your API is different: odd items are treated differently from the even ones. Moreover, it is a mistake to send an odd total number of operands. If for some reason you forget to put a string code on one of the lines, all values would silently become codes on the subsequent lines. Such API is very fragile, so I would strongly recommend agains it.

I think an API that lets your users add items in pairs would work better. If your compiler is C++11 compliant, you could also use [uniform initialization](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#init-list) syntax:

```
Data d = {
    {"cmd", server::value("test")}
,   {"url", server::value(url)}
,   {"code", server::value(std::to_string(code))}
};
```